# Stop plastic tablecloth cover from slipping

Tags: furniture

I have a 100% cotton tablecloth that I use on a table with a microwave on it. Because of the chance of food spillage, I also put a 20-gauge plastic sheet on top.

When I press buttons on the microwave, the microwave is pushed back slightly and drags the plastic with it.

Can you think of some way to anchor the plastic and/or the microwave where it is?

It occurs to me as I write this that I could insert some kind of spacer between the microwave and the wall so that it can't move backwards...

[image: tablecloth]

Comment: Why not use [table cloth clips](https://www.google.com/search?q=table+cloth+clips)?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Ah, didn't know those existed. Nice idea. If I can't think of anything else that would be more invisible, I'll probably do those.

Answer (score 1):

**Stop plastic tablecloth cover from slipping?**

Try putting a piece of wood to act as a brace behind your microwave and the wall, just big enough to stop the sliding effect of pressing those buttons.

In our lunch room we screwed a piece of 1” angle bar to the shelving unit and it works out okay.

It does not have to be screwed in place as long as the wood always the microwave and the wall in question.

If worried about scratching something you could glue felt to the wood where needed.

Just a thought!

Answer (score 1):

how about some fabric under the microwave feet?  so it'd be: MW - small fabric - plastic sheet - tablecloth - table.
That would break the friction between the microwave feet and the plastic.  if you happen to have felt pads somewhere, might work.